# UWP can not add ViewModel to MainPage. MainViewModel File not found

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

this problem drives me crazy. I have two Folders in my project: Views and ViewModels.

In View I have my MainPage.xaml
In ViewModel I have the BaseViewModel.cs and the MainViewModel.cs.

```
    class BaseViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void SetProperty<T>(ref T Storage, T Value, [CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(Storage, Value))
            return;
        else
        {
            Storage = Value;
        }

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

and my MainViewModel

```
    class MainViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    //Bands
    public Tuple<List<Band>, List<Band>> BandsFromMobileAndDesktop { get; private set; }
    public List<List<Band>> BandsFormCSV { get; private set; }


    private ObservableCollection<Band> finalList;

    public ObservableCollection<Band> FinalList
    {
        get { return finalList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref finalList, value); }
    }


    //Properties for View
    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set { SetProperty(ref text, value); }
    }


    public MainViewModel()
    {

        Text = "Hurricane festival 2017";

        CreateObservableBandList();

        var result = DatabaseController.GetBandsInTimeFrame(new DateTime(2017, 06, 23, 16, 0, 0, 0), new DateTime(2017, 06, 23, 19, 0, 0, 0));
        var a = 0;
    }

    async public Task GetBands()
    {
        //Get Bands
        //First list from Mobile Second From Desktop
        BandsFromMobileAndDesktop = await BandsCollector.BandsCollector.GetBandDates();
        BandsFormCSV = await BandsCollector.BandsCollector.getBandsFromCSV();

        BandsCollector.BandsCollector.FillBandDataFromCSVWithImageByteArray(BandsFormCSV, BandsFromMobileAndDesktop);


        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["AlreadyStarted"] = "true";
    }

    public void CreateObservableBandList()
    {
        //Get Bands only on first start
        if (ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["AlreadyStarted"] == null || ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["AlreadyStarted"].ToString() != "true")
        {
            Task task = Task.Run(async () => { await GetBands(); });
            task.Wait();

            getFinalList(BandsFormCSV);

            DatabaseController.CreateDataBase();

            foreach (var bandFromList in FinalList)
            {
                DatabaseController.AddBand(bandFromList);
            }
        }

    }

    public async Task FillCollection(ObservableCollection<Band> dayCollection, List<Band> dayList)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dayList.Count; i++)
        {
            dayCollection.Add(dayList[i]);
        }
    }


    public void getFinalList(List<List<Band>> CSVList)
    {
        FinalList = new ObservableCollection<Band>();

        for (int day = 0; day < CSVList.Count; day++)
        {
            if (0 == day)
            {
                for (int band = 0; band < CSVList[day].Count; band++)
                {
                    CSVList[day][band].Day = day;
                    FinalList.Add(CSVList[day][band]);
                }
            }

            else if (1 == day)
            {
                for (int band = 0; band < CSVList[day].Count; band++)
                {
                    CSVList[day][band].Day = day;
                    FinalList.Add(CSVList[day][band]);
                }
            }

            else if (2 == day)
            {
                for (int band = 0; band < CSVList[day].Count; band++)
                {
                    CSVList[day][band].Day = day;
                    FinalList.Add(CSVList[day][band]);

                }
            }

            else if (3 == day)
            {
                for (int band = 0; band < CSVList[day].Count; band++)
                {
                    CSVList[day][band].Day = day;
                    FinalList.Add(CSVList[day][band]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in my MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="MyApp.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MyApp"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:vm="using:MyApp.ViewModels"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

</Grid>
```

Now VS17 says that the file MainViewModel do not exist. But BaseViewModel works.

I copied all my code from another Project, I rebuild all and I used some fixes from StackOverflow which did not work in the end.

What is my mistake? I could not find it by myself.

Thanks

Agredo

Comment: I tested your above code snippet but cannot reproduce your issue. Clean and build will be successfully. Could you please provide [mcve]? I'm using vs17 and uwp app target 15063.

Comment: Are you sure that MainViewModel is in ViewModels namespace?

Comment: I tested your above code snippet but cannot reproduce your issue. Clean and build will be successfully. Could you please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? I'm using vs17 and uwp app target 15063. – Sunteen Wu - MSFT 7 hours ago. --- 

This sounds like my Visual Studio does not work correctly. Like I wrote: I copied my whole Project to a new Project, cleaned it an rebuild it. I used VS17 with uwp app target 15063 and 14393.

Comment: Yes MainViewModel ist in the Namespace myApp.ViewModels

Comment: When you type `<vm:` ,can the intelisense show the `MainViewModel` in the dropdownlist? And you can choose it instead of typing and try again.  Or repair your VS and try again. Otherwise, please provide a minimal reproduce project since your code snippet are not the full.

Comment: yes it was shown in IntelliSense. But i could solve it now. i chose "copy every time" in the property of MainViewModel and this works. My Base View Model did not Need this. But thanks guys.